# A conversão de um tipo de dados datetime2 em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo. A instrução foi finalizada

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho uma classe, cliente que tem a data do cadastro.

```
public class ClienteViewModel: Pessoa
{
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime? DataCancelamento { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime? DataUltimaAtualizacao { get; set; }
}
```

na minha view, eu seto um campo `input` com `DateTime.Now`, porém não mando esse campo para a action na controller, então o cliente.DataCadastro, vem `01/01/0001 00:00:00` eu sobreescrevi o método `SaveChanges();`

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("DataCadastro") != null))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("DataCadastro").IsModified = false;
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

para preencher meu campo `dataCadastro`como `DateTime.Now;`
minha controller está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ClienteViewModel cliente)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var clienteDomain = Mapper.Map<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>(cliente);
                if (clienteDomain.ClienteId == 0)
                {
                    _clienteApp.Adicionar(clienteDomain);
                }
                else {
                    _clienteApp.Atualizar(clienteDomain);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Cliente", clienteDomain);
            }
            ViewBag.RamoAtividadeId = new SelectList(_ramoapp.BuscarTodos(), "RamoId", "Descricao");
            ViewBag.VendedorId = new SelectList(_vendedorAppservico.BuscarTodos(), "VendedorId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.TabelaDePrecoId = new SelectList(_tabelaDePrecoAppServico.BuscarTodos(), "TabelaDePrecoId", "Descricao");
            return RedirectToAction("Cliente", cliente);
        }
```

Eu ja debuguei o código e não consegui achar o problema dessa data. não ta salvando porque toda vez da a seguinte mensagem:

> A conversão de um tipo de dados datetime2 em um tipo de dados datetime
>   resultou em um valor fora do intervalo. A instrução foi finalizada.

não sei o que está gerando esse problema.

na minha class `ClienteConfiguracao`, está assim:

```
Property(e => e.DataCadastro)
                .IsRequired()
                 .HasColumnType("datetime");
```

Alguém saberia me falar onde estou errando??

Comment: cara bota um breakpoint no seu savechanges e vê se ele de fato está pegando o datetime.now, esse erro acontece justamente por que o datetime tem um range menor que o datetime2, então em tese ele não contemplaria a data  01/01/0001 00:00:00

Comment: eu acho que o erro, ta na hora do mapeamento `var clienteDomain = Mapper.Map<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>(cliente);`

Comment: o erro estava no  meu Cliente.ComplementoPessoaFisica. --> ClienteViewModel.ComplementoPessoaFisicaViewModel. no meu dominio, eu tinha um campo `public Datatime DataDeNascimento {get;set;}` e na minha viewmodel estava assim--> public DateTime? DataDeNascimento {get: set;}, então, na hora de mapear, acho que dava alguma doidera,e na hora de salvar dava pau!